# What is going on with my foundation footer?

Tags: foundation, drainage, brick

I have a wet subfloor and been advised to lay a french drain around the house. I have been watching a lot of youtube videos on how to lay ag pipes immediately next to the foundation footer (the red circle in this diagram https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZKTo.jpg)

So when I dug a trench around my external wall, I was expecting the brick wall to go down deep into the soil and then to find the footer just like the picture above. Every french drain video I have seen had footers like this.

But my double brick house doesn't seem to have this. There is no wall that is buried into the soil. There are three levels (courses?) of brick on the bottom like it shows in these pictures  but they were more or less exposed / not buried.

[image: Overview of wall and foundation]

[image: brick foundation detail]

I dug a bit deeper expecting to the brick work to continue deeper but it was just dirt! I was surprised because aren't load bearing external brick walls meant to be buried deep into the ground? How is my external walls buried so shallow?

So is this three layer / course brick the "foundation footer" of my house? Or could there be something going deeper if I dig further? I don't want to dig underneath these three layers of bricks just in case they are supporting the load of the house.

(I'm asking because I want to put liquid rubber on external wall so water doesn't seep through it.)

Comment: Your first image link is broken. You may want to edit to fix that up.

Comment: Please edit your question and include these photos inline in your question.

Comment: Where in the world (generally, not your specific address) are you? If your area doesn't freeze, or doesn't freeze very deeply, you might not have any need for a deeply buried foundation.

Comment: There's no diagram in your 1st link. In fact it's the same set of pics as the 2nd link.

Comment: Pics from the 2nd link embedded. First link was dead and now points to where the 2nd link was.

Comment: The footing depends on what the soil conditions are in that area and the freeze depth, don’t go crazy with the digging or you will cause wall cracks. Since the wall looks solid I would work at digging a drainage, dry well or sump pit to move the water out of the trench.

Comment: Looks quite typical for a solid-walled UK house built in the late 19th or early 20th century. Building standards have changed a lot in the intervening years. If there's no sign of subsidence then nothing to worry about.

Comment: @FreeMan - thank you. I didnt even know I could embed the link directly here. Apologies.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - I live in Australia (sorry didnt know it was relevant) in Sydney. There is no freeze in this area. Thanks